# How can I adjust caption formatting without the caption package

Tags: captions, document-classes

I'm trying to build a custom class that matches my organization's template. I managed to get the formatting for table/figure captions to match using the caption package, but the caption package does not play nice with the tagpdf package, which I also need to use to meet accessibility requirements set by my organization.

Since I don't need the flexibility of the caption package, but rather I only need to match my design template, from googling around, it sounds like this should be possible by redefining `\@makecaption`, but I can't find any good specific guide for how to do this (I'm also finding it surprisingly difficult to find the source for the base report and article classes online; I use Overleaf so I can't just look in my own install).

Here is the formatting that I'm trying to achieve using the caption package

```
\RequirePackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}} % Define an uppercase option for main caption text
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1 #2}}} % Define uppercase option for caption label (e.g. "Figure 1")
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colonspace}{:\quad} % Define separator with an additional space between the colon and the caption text
%Full caption setup
\captionsetup{font={sf,small},%Font should be roughly size 9, Arial-equivalent
                labelfont={bf}, % Label should be bold
                format=hang, % Hanging indent
                textformat=uppercase, % Main text should be uppercase
                labelformat={uppercase}, %Label should be uppercase too
                labelsep=colonspace, % Separator should be a colon plus a large space
               position=top} % Space as if caption is on top (doesn't actually place the caption there, just sets the space appropriately).
```

Any guidance on how to code this would be appreciated.

Comment: if you redefine \@makecaption you will have to insert the tagging commands too, so look at the redefinition in latex-lab-testphase-float.sty

Comment: a)  Look at github  https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/develop/base/classes.dtx . But why don't you have your own installation? Why handicap yourself? Overleaf is great if you need to write a paper with co-authors, but not a good choice for developing.

Comment: @yannisl, thanks for the link; hazards of working on locked-down employer-owned machines.  Just seemed like it ought to be easier to find the source code in a google search.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, could it be that the redefinition in the testphase code is actually the problem here? I tried redefining \@makecaption without using the caption package (copying a template from another class), and the formatting instructions seem to be ignored. That may need to be another question, or an issue on the github...

Comment: well yes, the code in the testphase question redefine \@makecaption at begin document, if you want to win you will have to do it later.

Comment: Ah, that will do it. Makes it difficult to fix the formatting in a class, but that's a different issue. For posterity, an answer or guide for how to manually customize \@makecaption would be useful, but for my use case (using tagpdf and defining a custom class as a one-stop template for other users), looks like the way forward is unrelated to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: You can use \AtBeginDocument too, that should work fine.

Comment: If you searach here for `\@makecaption` you will find many modified versions.  The best bet is to look at the source, which found in the document class,  Also caption, float and floatrow packages (which is why they tend to be incompativle).